# What is the best way to create cross-platform mobile apps?

Tags: mobile, cross-platform

We're trying to put together a couple of simple apps that we would like to release on the iPhone and Android, and also on the desktop (Windows and Mac), if possible. The prototype is being built using HTML & Javascript, and it would be ideal to use it as a base to create native apps for multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using html and javascript, [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) is probably your best bet for iPhone and Android.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be jquery mobile:

http://jquerymobile.com/